# Conditional Debug code hit in Release mode

Tags: c#, .net

I'm encountering the strange situation that a part in my code that shouldn't even be compiled is being executed.

I have Debug and Release modes, my code is the following:

```c
#if DEBUG
    Debug.WriteLine(text);
#endif
```

Now, I'm running my application in Release mode using Visual Studio (to check another issue) and find that the text is being written in the Output window. What's worse, I can even set a breakpoint in this line and it is being hit.

Any idea what kind of misconfiguration I might have in my project/solution?

Edit:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyTitle>name</AssemblyTitle>
    <Product>name</Product>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
    <Copyright>Copyright © 2022</Copyright>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release</Configurations>
    <UseWPF>True</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Edit 2:

Conditional compilation symbols are

```
TRACE;RELEASE;NETFRAMEWORK;NET48;
```

Final edit so far:

The project in question is a dependency (a dll) referenced by my main app. Although I of course tried to Clean and Rebuild, something is off on that end. I manually deleted all bin and obj folders and now I get the expected behavior: no lines written to the Output anymore and no breakpoints hit. Which means, that it referenced a debug version of the dll before. Will have to sort out the building/cleaning process a bit, it seems...

Comment: see in your csproj-file if the debug-variable is set in release-mode.

Comment: Please post your csproj

Comment: Are you doing that thing where you build Debug and Release in the same folder?

Comment: Check the configuration for the projects as well in the Configuration Manager. Just because your solution is in Release mode doesn't mean the projects all are

Comment: and even *if* they are doesn't mean the env-var is not set

Comment: Configuration manager looks fine to me.

Comment: If you go to project properties, under Build | General, what does it have for "Conditional compilation symbols"?

Comment: I presume you've tried to Clean and Rebuild?

Comment: You say "Conditional compilation symbols are": given that conditional compilation symbols are defined in the csproj, and your csproj doesn't include these, where did you get those values from? You've also only posted part of your csproj: can you post the whole thing?

Comment: `Configuration manager looks fine to me` - "fine" means many things..  Do you have 'release' on top of it as the selected solution config, and you see that every single project is in listed in this window as having 'release' mode selected and also has 'build' checkbox checked?

Comment: I doubt it's related to conditional compilation symbols, even with DEBUG set the breakpoint mentioned shouldn't be hit (at least as far as I know)

Comment: @madmonk46 Sure it should...

Comment: It is kind of strange to me that you run in release mode with visual studio and breakpoints and it isnt considered debugging. I am confused. Try running it outside Visual studio with both builds.

Comment: @madmonk46 why shouldn't it be hit? in debug builds, both DEBUG 'preprocessor' symbol is present, and Debug.Writeline isn't trimmed out either, so a breakpoint placed there should totally be hit. Please explain.

Comment: the question is: **why** is the prepocessor-symbol `DEBUG` set? From the above csproj-file it shoulnd't, assuming OP is running release and all projects are set to release, of course in ConfigurationManager.

Comment: @shahkalpesh it's not about whever he is doing debugging or not. You can run any tool you like in any mode, and if you try to fix a problem, it could still be called "doing debugging". The question is about conditional compilation and #if. They are driven by symbols, defined by configration, and effective cfg depends on active ProprtyGroups in csproj files and few more things. OP says s/he's pretty sure that he activated Release mode, so RELEASE symbol should be present, not DEBUG, and if that symbol is not present, then the line should get grayed out and not be compiled to final dll/exe/etc.

Comment: OP hasn't posted the whole csproj, hasn't explained where the "Conditional compilation symbols are" came from, and we're trusting them on "Configuration manager looks fine to me". Any of those could be hiding the issue

Comment: @quetzalcoatl usually, in Release mode, compiler optimisations are enabled which will remove debugging symbols and stop breakpoints from being hit, although you're right that that isn't necessarily the case. If you switch the optimisations off, you will still hit breakpoints. The fact that OP is hitting breakpoints is what leads me to believe it's not just a conditional compilation symbol, because you wouldn't generally turn off the default optimisations, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: Thanks to everybody so far.
1. "Configuration manager looks fine" means that all projects are shown as in Release when the Solution build configuration is set to Release
2. Conditional compilation symbols are from the project settings (the UI ones). I'm also confused as to where they are from, because I don't see them in the csproj file.
3. I get the "You are debugging a Release build" warning, so that adds to my confusion.

Comment: Does that mean that when the breakpoint is hit, the IDE doesn't actually show you what line it's on? You might have "Just My Code" debugging disabled if that is the case, which would explain why the breakpoint is being hit, optimised code isn't seen as user code in this context. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2022#BKMK__NET_Framework_Just_My_Code Doesn't explain where the definition of DEBUG is coming from though

Comment: Thanks, guys. See my final edit. I will have to check why the main app kept on referencing a Debug dll. Probably something is off on that end. but that would be another question.